# Is this resistance ship a set on its own, or part of another set?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I can't find this ship on Brickset, so it's either unlisted (unlikely) or came with another set.

Can anyone ID it, please?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This A-wing is part of [75196: A-Wing vs. TIE Silencer Microfighters](https://brickset.com/sets/75196-1/A-Wing-vs-TIE-Silencer-Microfighters)
[image]

Comment: Ah, they come as a pair. I'd not got to the other craft yet. Thank you.